# Inner merge two DataFrames on string partial match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have the following two data frames

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['I am feeling very well',1],['It is hard to believe this happened',0],
                                  ['What is love?',1], ['No new friends',0],
                             ['I love this show',1],['Amazing day today',1]]),
                                columns = ['message','sentiment'])

temp_truncated = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['I am feeling very',1],['It is hard to believe',1],
                                  ['What is',1], ['Amazing day',1]]),
                                columns = ['message','cutoff'])
```

My idea is to create a third DataFrame that would represent the inner join between `temp` and `temp_truncated` by finding matches in `temp` that start with / contain the strings in `temp_truncated`

Desired Output:

```
     message                             sentiment   cutoff            
0    I am feeling very well               1          1
1    It is hard to believe this happened  0          1
2    What is love                         1          1
3    Amazing day today                    1          1
```

Comment: Your output doesn't fully match the provided data ;)

Comment: @mozway I just realized I used a different sample. Fixed. Looking into the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
import re
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, temp_truncated['message']))

key = temp['message'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False)

out = (temp
 .merge(temp_truncated.rename(columns={'message': 'sub'}),
        left_on=key, right_on='sub')
 .drop(columns='sub')
)
```

Output:

```
                               message sentiment cutoff
0               I am feeling very well         1      1
1  It is hard to believe this happened         0      1
2                        What is love?         1      1
3                    Amazing day today         1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [**`rapidfuzz`**](https://pypi.org/project/rapidfuzz/) with [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
#pip install rapidfuzz
from rapidfuzz import process

out = (
        temp_truncated
           .assign(message_adapted = (temp_truncated['message']
                                       .map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, temp['message']))).str[0])
           .merge(temp, left_on="message_adapted", right_on="message", how="left", suffixes=("_", ""))
           .drop(columns=["message_adapted", "message_"])
           .loc[:, temp.columns.tolist() + ["cutoff"]]
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)
                               message sentiment cutoff
0               I am feeling very well         1      1
1  It is hard to believe this happened         0      1
2                        What is love?         1      1
3                    Amazing day today         1      1
```

Comment: Note that fuzzy matching and substring matching is not exactly the same thing. If you replace `Amazing Day` with `Amazing Job` in `temp_truncated`, this will still match (it probably shouldn't)

Comment: For me, there was no difference especially when I got the exact expected output by the OP. I will delete my answer, thank you so much, mozway ;)

Comment: You don't have to delete, that's still nice, but it's important to make the difference clear ;)

Comment: @abokey no please do keep the answer up, as the comment on how fuzzy matching differs from actual matching is important and must stay here for future reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.startswith`, or other `str.` functions such as `str.contains` in an apply to get a matches dataframe:

```
matches = temp_truncated.message.apply(
    lambda x: temp[temp.message.str.startswith(x)]['sentiment']
).dropna(how='all')
```

This `matches` dataframe contains the rows of `temp_truncated` which has a match with one of the rows in `temp`. These `temp` rows are the columns of the `matches` dataframe. The values are the sentiment values of these `temp` rows.
With this you can filter the `temp` dataframe with only matched rows and then enrich it with the corresponding cutoff value from `temp_truncated`:

```
df = temp.iloc[matches.columns]
df.index = matches.index
df = df.merge(temp_truncated['cutoff'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Result matches your desired output:

```
    message                             sentiment   cutoff
0   I am feeling very well              1           1
1   It is hard to believe this happened 0           1
2   What is love?                       1           1
3   Amazing day today                   1           1
```